# How to remove dots from this combination in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have this combination in a string:

```
"I am tagging @username1.blah. and @username2.test. and @username3."
```

I tried this:

```
preg_replace('/\@^|(\.+)/', '', 'I am tagging @username1.blah. and @username2.test. and @username3. in my status.');
```

But the result is:

```
"I am tagging @username1blah and @username2test and @username3 in my status"
```

The above result is not what I wanted.

This is what I want to achieve:

```
"I am tagging @username.blah and @username2.test and @username3 in my status."
```

Could someone help me what I have done wrong in the pattern?

Many thanks,
Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will replace dots at the end of "words" that are starting with `@`

```
$input = "I am tagging @username1.blah. and @username2.test. and @username3. in my status.";
echo preg_replace('/(@\S+)\.(?=\s|$)/', '$1', $input);
```

`(@\S+)\.(?=\s|$)` will match a dot at the end of a non whitespace (`\S`) series when the dot is followed by whitespace or the end of the string (`(?=\s|$)`)

Answer (score 3):

I don't like regex very much, but when you are sure that the dots you want to remove are always followed by a space, you could do something like this:

```
php > $a = "I am tagging @username1.blah. and @username2.test. and @username3.";
php > echo str_replace(". ", " ", $a." ");
I am tagging @username1.blah and @username2.test and @username3
```

Comment: This will remove dots even if the word doesn't begin with `@`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
preg_replace('/\.(\s+|$)/', '\1', $r);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, it is quite useful - however I edited the question because I want the changes only apply to the word that started with '@' symbol. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/\.( |$)/', '\1', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
preg_replace("/(@\S+)\.(?:\s|$)/", "$1", $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/\@\w+(\.\w+)?(?<dot>\.)/
```

That will match all dots and name them in the dot group